# OpenCV with C++, the use of cv::utils::fs::glob() function

Tags: c++, opencv

I am using OpenCV with C++ and want to read files from a folder with a filename filter. The official document from OpenCV seems a bit confusing on the filter syntax :

```
void cv::utils::fs::glob    (   const cv::String &  directory,
                                const cv::String &  pattern,
                                std::vector< cv::String > &     result,
                                bool    recursive = false,
                                bool    includeDirectories = false 
                            )
```

> **pattern** : filter pattern (based on '*'/'?' symbols). Use empty string to disable filtering and return all results

I tried using an empty `cv::string ""` or `cv::string "*.jpg"` as pattern, it worked out well with all the files inside directory being read.

My question is, what is the use of symbols `/` and `?`. Could you please provide with some examples?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`?` is a wildcard for just one character, `?.jpg` will fit `1.jpg`, `2.jpg`, but not `10.jpg`.

`/` is a folder separator, likely to be used if you include directories, then you may specify from which particular directory you want your files to be read: `images/*.jpg` etc.